# Example of credit card usage data

Tags: finance, data-format, bank

I want to understand the data saved when a person uses his or her credit card in a shop or online. Is there a common data set format for this? If so, what does it contain? Furthermore, can anyone point to an example dataset?

I know that in the telecommunications industry one standard format used is the call detail record (CDR) for making calls or sending texts. I'm trying to find the "bank equivalent" of such a format for credit card usage.

I've seen [A typical bank database for credit card accounts?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6214/a-typical-bank-database-for-credit-card-accounts) and [Credit card metadata database](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3930/credit-card-metadata-database), but these are related to the numbers used for the accounts associated with the credit cards, whereas I'm interested in the information captured every time the card is used.